# Ubuntu dual boot with Win 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu with Win 7. I've created a partition in 
my hard drive  in windows.

[image]

So the problem is, when I am booting from my DVD disc with Ubuntu burned into it and come to the part when choosing how to install Ubuntu: the installer doesn't seem to find my windows 7 so there's no "Install alongside" option nor my partitions in the something else option. I've read many questions but I don’t really know what to do. Probably because I am really new at this type of stuff. Also forgot to say. In the try Ubuntu option, I opened that disc partition program (don't know what it is called) strangely Ubuntu found all my partitions:

[image]

I also tried to run the installer there too but as expected it didn't make any difference. If you could help me with my problem it would be highly appreciated.

EDIT: `sudo parted --list` command output:

```
Warning: /dev/sda contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT 
table. However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as 
it should. Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't 
understand GPT partition tables. Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, 
and are now using an msdos partition table. Is this a GPT partition 
table?
 –Yes or no?
```

**EDIT 2**: Sorry for not making this edit. The problem has been solved for a very long time. The problem was the Ubuntu 14 installer for some reason it simply didn't detect my windows 7 partition. However it may just be me since i had windows 7 ultimate, im not sure. Anyways the ubuntu 15 installer worked just fine and it could dual boot and create a partition without any problems.

Regards, Bablooo

Comment: You cannot create Linux partitions in Windows. Post this from terminal in live installer: `sudo parted -l` Post above so you can preserve formatting.

Comment: Could you be more specific what I should do? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** what @oldfred meatn is: Press [Ctrl][Alt][T] and then type: `sudo parted --list`[enter] in the black screen (the "Terminal" and then  [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the above command into your question and then click "Save"...

Comment: This is what the terminal said when I typed sudo parted --list  Warning: /dev/sda contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table.
However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should.
Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT
partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an
msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT partition table?

Comment: So what it asks me is if i have a GPT partition table. I have no idea what the heck that is xD. But how do I find out if it is or not? Best regards, Pablo. c:

Comment: @BabloooTheCookie You can answer your own questions next time, and then accept that answer.  Editing the title to say '[SOLVED]' does not actually mark the question as "answered" and "solved".  Feel free to accept the answer I just posted which quotes your edit to make it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *This answer is from the OP, and taken from an edit to their question.  Please mark this as accepted, Original Poster.*

---

> The problem was the Ubuntu 14 installer for some reason it simply didn't detect my windows 7 partition. However it may just be me since i had windows 7 ultimate, im not sure. Anyways the ubuntu 15 installer worked just fine and it could dual boot and create a partition without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you boot back in Windows and delete the partition you created for Linux that should solve your problem. Linux typically operates on an ext3 or ext4 file system that isn't supported in Windows. It's best to therefore leave some empty unpartitioned space on your hard drive and Linux will create a partition itself for you when you install it.

Comment: I deleted the unlocated partition that i created but it didn't make change. Thank you very much for helping me out though c: Best regards, Pablo